# Remove .htaccess in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file in a directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/launch [R,L] 
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Basically, this forces any and all pages below mysite.com/launch to an SSL version of https://www.mysite.com/launch/index.html.

However, for a single sub-directory under /launch I need to be able to allow access without user being redirected.

For example, if they navigate to www.mysite.com/launch/files/photos, then they should be able to access individual files inside the /photos directory.

Do I use another .htaccess file inside the /photos directory, or do I modify the existing .htaccess file in the /launch directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used something like that.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!intranet/|cv/)(.+)$ somedirname/$1 [L]
RewriteRUle ^$ somedirname/ [L]
```

so when mysite.com/intranet is called it goes into the folder intranet
or when mysite.com/cv is called it goes into the cv folder

but in this case when no subdir is called it forces to go into 'somedirname'

of course you can change the last `rewriterule to RewriteRule ^(.*)$` to `https://www.mysite.com/launch [R,L]`

putting the other rewriterule on top for checking it is not the directory they can access

so you end up with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(?!subdir1/|subdir2/)(.+)$ launch/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/launch [R,L] 
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

now
www.mysite.com/subdir1
and
www.mysite.com/subdir2
can be opened in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `RewriteCond` above your rules, like so:

```
# Put this above the existing RewriteCond
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !launch/files/photos
...
```